# How to make code run automatically when switching to a new ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a function which updates two labels in a ViewController. How can I make it so that, once I switch to this ViewController, both of these labels get updated without need user input such as a button?

```
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var highScoreLabel: UILabel!

func updateScores() {
    scoreLabel.text = "\(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "EndScore"))"
    if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "LastGameMode") == "Easy" {
        highScoreLabel.text = "\(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "EasyHighScore"))"
    } else if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "LastGameMode") == "Normal" {
        highScoreLabel.text = "\(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "NormalHighScore"))"
    } else if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "LastGameMode") == "Hard" {
        highScoreLabel.text = "\(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "HardHighScore"))"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to *override* `viewWillAppear` and call `updateScores()` inside it.

Your code should look like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    updateScores()
}
```